# ASPNET MVC filter, WebAPI filter, ASPNET core MVC filter, are three different things?

Tags: asp.net-core

Filters in ASP.NET confuse me. I have seen 3 kinds of filters:

MVC filter `System.Web.Mvc.IAction​Filter`

WebAPI filter `System.Web.Http.Filters.IActionFilter`

Core MVC filter `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.IActionFilter`

Is there a Core WebAPI filter?

I have a WebAPI filter which uses Dependency Injection via constructor parameters. It works well in my WebAPI application which uses Unity as IOC container.

```
container.Register<IMyService, MyService>();
container.Register<LogActionFilter>();

var filterInstance = container.Resolve<LogActionFilter>();
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters.Add(filterInstance);
```

The following attribute `Log` is defined as a simple attribute which only has three properties. The `LogActionFilter` above will check if an action has the `Log` attribute using `GetCustomeAttribute<LogAttribute>()`.

```
[Log(Enabled=true, Level=2, Format="xxxx")]
public void MyAction()
{
}
```

Now I want to migrate it to ASP.NET CORE. Can I use DI for CORE filters?

I only find `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.IActionFilter` in ASPNET CORE. And it seems hard to use DI. Still don't know how to register such a filter.

I know there is `ServiceFilter(typeof(XxxFilter))` but it's not good to pass paramters like  `[Log(Enabled=true, Level=2, Format="xxxx")]`

Anyone has an example of CORE filter?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR: They are all pretty much the same thing.

- [`System.Web.Mvc.IAction​Filter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.iactionfilter?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) is an MVC action filter from ASP.NET MVC.
- [`System.Web.Http.Filters.IActionFilter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/hh834418%28v%3dvs.108%29) is an MVC action filter from ASP.NET MVC WebAPI.
- [`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.IActionFilter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.filters.iactionfilter?view=aspnetcore-2.2) is an MVC action filter from ASP.NET Core.

So the common theme is that they are all MVC action filters. That means that they run around the execution of an action within the context of an MVC framework.

The difference is just that they are used for *different* MVC frameworks.

ASP.NET MVC is the older MVC framework running on the .NET Framework. WebAPI is the framework that was developed specifically to create APIs for the web. It is generally similar to ASP.NET MVC but is still a separate entity.

With ASP.NET Core, the new and current open source MVC framework by Microsoft, the distinction between “MVC” and “WebAPI” was removed and instead you just have a single MVC framework included within ASP.NET Core. So you just have ASP.NET Core, and there you happen to use action filters around MVC actions.

There is very good [documentation on MVC filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-2.2) for ASP.NET Core. There is also a section explicitly about [dependency injection in filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-2.2#dependency-injection). You can use the `ServiceFilter` or `TypeFilter` to properly use dependency injection within your filters. `ServiceFilter` is used when you want to resolve the filter completely from the DI container, while you can use `TypeFilter` to also provide some parameters directly in the attribute. The [example on `TypeFilter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-2.2#typefilterattribute) ironically also uses a logging example.

That being said, logging is generally not the best use case for action filters since ASP.NET Core actually does log around the execution of actions by default.